# ¿Por qué la versión ejecutable de mi programa Python no ejecuta os.listdir y os.path.isdir correctamente en Windows 10 como sistema operativo?

Tags: python-3.x, diccionarios, windows10, depuración, pyinstaller

Tengo este programa que imprime un diccionario, el cual tiene, los **nombres de carpetas** como `llaves` y **nombres de archivo** como `valores` para una `ruta` dada:

```
import os
if os.name == 'nt': # Let's add some colors for the lulz
    from ctypes import windll
    k = windll.kernel32
    k.SetConsoleMode(k.GetStdHandle(-11), 7)

# Main method
the_dictionary_list = {}
print('\u001b[43mHi Sailor! I am "SAND-wich", a simple program built by @NoahVerner\033[0m')
print('\n')
time.sleep(2)
def check_path(infile):
    return os.path.exists(infile)    
        
first_entry = input('Tell me the path in which your folders with images are located:')

while True:
    
    if check_path(first_entry) == False:
        print('\n')
        print('This PATH is invalid!')
        first_entry = input('Tell me the RIGHT PATH in which your folders with ONLY images are located:')
        
    elif check_path(first_entry) == True:
        print('\n')
        final_output = first_entry
        break

print('This PATH has the following folders with the following files:')
print('\n')
for name in os.listdir(first_entry):
    if os.path.isdir(name):
        path = os.path.basename(name)
        print(f'\u001b[45m{path}\033[0m')
        list_of_file_contents = os.listdir(path)
        print(f'\033[46m{list_of_file_contents}')
        the_dictionary_list[path] = list_of_file_contents
print('\n')
print('\u001b[43mthe_dictionary_list:\033[0m')
print(the_dictionary_list)
print('\n')
```

Dentro de un archivo `.py`, el código de arriba funciona correctamente sin arrojar ningún error.

[image: Spyder output]

Luego, después de exportar este programa como un ÚNICO archivo ejecutable usando la siguiente sentencia en `Símbolo del sistema`:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --icon=./SAND-wich_icon.ico SAND-wich.py
```

Obtengo las siguientes carpetas:

[image: folders]

De las cuales, la carpeta `dist` contiene el archivo `.exe` que quiero.

[image: .exe file]

Entonces ejecuto `SAND-wich.exe` como `Admin`, **no sin antes tener mi** `Antivirus AVG` **desactivado** (ya que este tampoco no permite ejecutar mi programa correctamente)

Y sucede que mi archivo ejecutable **SÍ RECONOCE que la** `ruta` **que estoy pasando como entrada ES SIN DUDA UNA RUTA**.

Pero, **NO RETORNA el diccionario deseado con los valores esperados**, **pues retorna un diccionario vacío**:

[image: empty dictionary]

¿Qué está generando este problema? Asuma que la `ruta` que estoy pasando en ambos casos es la misma, y sólamente contiene carpetas las cuales sólamente contienen imágenes `png`, y el `Sistema Operativo` en el cual el archivo ejecutable se ejecutará será `Windows 10`.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo descubrí, fue algo tonto en el código del archivo `.py` realmente

```
for name in os.listdir(first_entry):
    backslash = "\\"
    if os.path.isdir(first_entry+backslash+name):
        path = os.path.basename(name)
        print(f'\u001b[45m{path}\033[0m')
        list_of_file_contents = os.listdir(first_entry+backslash+path)
        print(f'\033[46m{list_of_file_contents}')
        the_dictionary_list[path] = list_of_file_contents
print('\n')
print('\u001b[43mthe_dictionary_list:\033[0m')
print(the_dictionary_list)
print('\n')
```

Comparación hecha en [Diffchecker](https://www.diffchecker.com/), versión anterior vs versión nueva.
[image: solved]